# Copying Struct to a Pointer array in a function C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

i have a huge problem allocating memory in C

i have this struct

```
typedef struct{
int x;
int y;
}T;
```

i want to create a function that dynamically adds a structs to a pointer.
something like:

```
int main()
{
 T* t;
 f(&t);
 free(t);
}
```

up to this point i think everything is ok, now the function is where i get lost

```
void f(T** t)
{
 T t1;
 T t2;
 T t3;
 //first i malloc
 *t=malloc(sizeof(T)*T_MAX_SIZE);//i want another function to make the array bigger, but this is not as important as the problem
 t1.x=11;
 t1.y=12;
 t2.x=21;
 t2.y=22;
 t3.x=31;
 t3.y=32;
//now i want to copy the values from t1,t2,t3 to t[0],t[1],t[2]
 memcpy(&(*t[0]),&t1,sizeof(T));
 memcpy(&(*t[1]),&t2,sizeof(T));
 memcpy(&(*t[2]),&t3,sizeof(T));


}
```

i do not know the correct way of copying these structs.

the point of doing this is to use t out of the function
(in the main)

many thanks :D

Comment: I'm removing the C++ tag because it is irrelevant here.

Comment: @juanchopanza changed to a relevant tag, thanks :)

Comment: try `(*t)[0] = t1;(*t)[1] = t2;(*t)[2] = t3;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `memcpy` calls are incorrect.

In the expression `&(*t[0])`, the array index has top precedence, followed by the pointer indirection.  So with explicit parenthesis it looks like `&(*(t[0]))`.

So it first tries to array subscript `t`, which is the address of `t` in main.  In the case of `t[0]` it still works, but `t[1]` references something past that variable, invoking undefined behavior.  You want the array index of what `t` points to, which is `(*t)[i]`.

So the memcpy calls should be:

```
memcpy(&((*t)[0]),&t1,sizeof(T));
memcpy(&((*t)[1]),&t2,sizeof(T));
memcpy(&((*t)[2]),&t3,sizeof(T));
```

Comment: many thanks it worked, can you explain me why it worked? &((*t)[0] , that means the memory value of the pointer t in position 0-1-2?

Comment: is possible to do this moving the pointer? , something like memcpy(&((*t)+1)...;?

Comment: That won't work because `*t + 1` is not an lvalue, so you can't take the address of it.  But you can do `memcpy(*t+1,&t1,sizeof(T));`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any copy functions to assign one structure to another - you simply equate them. So if you have

```
T var1 = {1, 2};
T var2 = var1;
```

the whole of `var1` is copied to `var2`. Amending your (simplified) program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define T_MAX_SIZE 10

typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
}T;

void f(T** t)
{
    T t1;
    *t=malloc(sizeof(T)*T_MAX_SIZE);
    t1.x=11;
    t1.y=12;
    (*t)[0] = t1;
}

int main(void) {
    T* t;
    f(&t);
    printf ("Result %d %d\n", t[0].x, t[0].y);
    free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Result 11 12
```

Comment: this is solve my problem and is a valid solution too, many thanks ;D

Comment: it is possible to do this moving the pointer instead of going to the position?

Comment: @LuisDanielRubiera, I think you should experiment, and post a new question if you get problems. Don't be afraid to "break" the program: the OS and the hardware are well engineered to protect the computer from accidental damage. But be aware, if you move the pointer you can't `free` the memory. Use a copy of the pointer.

Comment: many thanks for the information,is there any guide to know how to free the pointer after i move it? or how to use a copy of it correctly?

Comment: Work with a copy, then you can `free` the original value. Just make sure you don't lose the original pointer value, if you try to `free(changedpointer)` it will be bad do!

Comment: ...and remember, if you add 1 to a pointer, its value will be incremented by `sizeof` its type. It will only be incremented by 1 if its type is `char*`. Adding 1 to a pointer to `T` will increment the pointer by `sizeof(T)`.

Comment: you think is a good practice to move the pointer? or should i stay with possition?

Comment: how can i assign a moved copy of the pointer? and move it correctly?